# Is there a way to fix October CMS not finding a configuration file?

Tags: laravel, server, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I have a website developed using October CMS based on laravel. When I run the local site I get no error but when I host the website on Linux Server Ubuntu I get an error whenever I visit a plugin to create events saying: 
`Unable to find configuration file config_form.yaml defined for Backend\Behaviors\FormController` 
The error looks like below:
[image]

Is this concerning permissions? Because I tried setting the www folder **777** permissions for all user groups so what is concerning is the site is running locally without a problem.

Comment: Where does `$this->getConfigPath()` point to? Make sure that on the server this also points to the location where the config file would be stored.

Comment: it seems the file is missing on the server you can check it once , if actually file is there or not

Comment: @geertjanknapen I do not know yet where its pointing to. Its october CMS code. I am currently trying to find where. On a windows machine there is no error but on linux there is

Comment: @HardikSatasiya I am currently looking to find which file its pointing to

Comment: @geertjanknapen I found the file and it exists. On windows there is no error but linux there is an error.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya the file exits on the server